# Magento 2 Add customers grid in custom admin form

Tags: magento-2.1, adminform, customer-grid

I want to show customers grid in our custom admin form where I can select a particular customer so how to get this customer grid list in our form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add few lines in your ui componnet form file
as follows

```
 <insertListing name="customer_custom_listing">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataLinks" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="exports" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="behaviourType" xsi:type="string">simple</item>
                    <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">customer_custom_listing</item>
                    <item name="render_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- You can add as many as you want -->
                        <item name="id" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:data.entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_custom_listing.customer_custom_listing.columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </insertListing>
```

Here You can see I have added `customer_custom_listing`  in my form and added new customer_custom_listing.xml file for additional customization

you can add any existing listing using this component

hope this may help you.